# Создание графика отображения температуры процессора в реальном времени на NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, графики

У меня появилась задача отображать в реальном времени температуру процессора через `Web` приложение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данное `Web` приложение будет содержать в себе всю информацию о компьютере, в том числе и температуру процессора. Проблема в том, что температура процессора должна обновляться каждые 5 секунд, и это обновление должно быть изображено в `Web` приложение в виде какого-то графика. Я решил сохранять температуру процессора в базу данных, где будут сохраняться временные метки данной температуры и сама температура. Всю эту логику исполняет демон, написанный на `с++`. Со стороны `Web` приложения, я должен извлечь уже полученные временные метки с температурой и отобразить их на графике температуры. Вопрос заключается в следующем - какую библиотеку лучше всего использовать для этого, так как я чайник в `js`, а проект мне нужно сделать в ближайшее время. В идеале было бы, если данная библиотека интегрировалась в `html` код, и легко бы отображала полученные данные. Также, скорее всего, помимо графика отображения температуры процессора, будет и график отображения нагрузки процессора в реальном времени, а возможно, и что-то другое...

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: grafana смотрели?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Да, возможно буду использовать ее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна из полулрных это charts.js, но как по мне тяжело кастомизировать для начинающих, все таки работа с канвасом. Советую [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo), отрисовка идет в svg с очень кастомной настройкой каждого элемента. Но прежде всего посмотрите на лицензию.